# Macbook Pro 17 Early 2008 - Mountain Lion - SSD Slow Performance

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, ssd, performance, trim

I have noticed significant performance degradation on my Samsung EVO running on an Old Macbook Pro, Intel Core 2 duo. Are there any SSD tips that I should apply to this hard drive? Will Trim Enabler make things quicker?

Comment: What do you exactly mean with slow?

Comment: Did you build it into the CD slot or did you replace your HDD?

Comment: HDD Replaced, Mountain Lion Clean Install. Overall lagginess after 2 months of usage, no trim enabled.

Comment: Did you measure it's speed? Do you have SMART data available?

Comment: yes. it's roughly 135MB/s on both read write speeds, as it's attached to a SATA 1 controller. Nevertheless, the overall issue is with lagginess rather than slowness. Mission control is kinda choppy etc. It was working fine for 2 months but it seems to have slowed down eversince.

Comment: You should use smartmontools to check if your SSD is broken.

Comment: can't find an OSX Binary.

Comment: used smart utility instead, everything seems to be ok. Maybe my 7 year old macbook pro is dying..

Comment: Did you run Apple Hardware Test?

Comment: 4vdc/1/40000003

Comment: http://s28.postimg.org/qznb3jzkc/Photo_21_10_2014_17_03_04.jpg